# Extract value from (sqlite3) query in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

For a course I'll be making a website using javascript and a sqlite3 database, but I'm having some trouble getting actual values from a query. I have the following piece of code that checks whether a name is already in the database or not:

```js
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./myFile.db');    

db.serialize(function () {

  db.get("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = 'aName')", function (err, row) {
    console.log(row);
    
    if (row == 0) {                          //Doesn't work
       console.log("Name doesn't exist");
    }
    if (row == 1) {                          //Doesn't work
      console.log("Name does exist");
    }
  });
        
});

db.close();
```

Logging the row gives the following output when the name is / isn't in the table.

> { 'EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = \'aName\')': 1 }
>
> { 'EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = \'aName\')': 0 }

The query does seem to work since the row ends with 0 when the name isn't in the database and with a 1 when it is. Now I'm trying to do something like `if (row == 0)` , but this doesn't work since row is a whole list/array/map/something? and not just a 0 (or 1).

So my question is, is there some way to extract just the 0/1 value or a true/false from row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem for anyone who happens to have a similar problem. The EXISTS makes for a weird json ish value type that I still don't understand, but I found a work around. I changed my query to `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = 'aName')` and changed my if statement to `if (!row)` if the row doesn't exist and have used an `else` instad of the second `if`for when to row does already exist.